# Using ORDER BY to sort data

Tags: sql, perl, oracle, sql-order-by

This is the data that I would like to sort.

```
AAAAAAAA    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
BBBBBBBB    0.0.0.0   hs01.morestuff.net
CCCCCCCC    0.0.0.0   hs01.evenmorestuff.net
DDDDDDDD    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
EEEEEEEE    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
FFFFFFFF    0.0.0.0   hs01.evenmorestuff.net
GGGGGGGG    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
HHHHHHHH    0.0.0.0   hs01.evenmorestuff.net
```

This is the result of the ORDER BY:

```
AAAAAAAA    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
BBBBBBBB    0.0.0.0   hs01.morestuff.net
CCCCCCCC    0.0.0.0   hs01.evenmorestuff.net
DDDDDDDD    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
EEEEEEEE    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
FFFFFFFF    0.0.0.0   hs01.evenmorestuff.net
GGGGGGGG    0.0.0.0   hs01.stuff.net
HHHHHHHH    0.0.0.0   hs01.evenmorestuff.net
```

THE SAME OUTPUT, so something went wrong.

This is what I have tried thus far

```
$dbh_source2 = DBI->
connect("dbi:Oracle:host=????;port=????;sid=????",'????','????');

$SEL = "SELECT DISTINCT 
               PE_LOOPBACK_IP,
               PE_FQDN 
          FROM TABLE_NAME
         WHERE SITE_NAME = ? 
      ORDER BY PE_FQDN";

$sth = $dbh_source2->prepare($SEL);
```

This does not work and does not sort the last column by the name.  Does `ORDER BY` only sort based on the first character?  Are the numbers that are within the name causing it to fail?

Here is the code that I use to display the data:

```
print '<table border=1>';
print '<tr>';
print '<th>Tower name</th>';
print '<th>SUR IP</th>';
print '<th>SUR FQDN</th>';
print '</tr>';
foreach my $data_line (@raw_data) {
        chomp $data_line;

        $sth->execute($data_line);

        while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
              #Print data into cells#
              print "<tr>";
              print "<td>$data_line</td>";
              foreach (@row) {
                print "<td>$_</td>";
              }
              print "</tr>";
              #print "<$data_line>\t @row\n";

    }
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: i'd be more suspicious of the `distinct` keyword than the order by.

Comment: It looks right to me. Are there 3 columns in there or only one?

Comment: What makes you believe that Oracle is not sorting the data by the PE_FQDN column?  What is the output you are getting and what is the output you expect?

Comment: I get the same exact output when I use the ORDER BY Statement that I get when I don't use it at all.

Comment: Is it sorting case sensitively? If it use, use ORDER BY lower(col)

Comment: even with the lower(PE_FQDN) it shows the exact same output, nothing changes

Comment: @Justin - I expect the output to sort by the FQDN column so that all of the same FQDN's are grouped together.  When I use the ORDER BY statement it doesn't do anything and displays the data the same way.

Comment: Are there whitespace in that column? How about "select distinct TRIM(PE_FQDN)"

Comment: @jmg0880 - Can you post exactly what Oracle is returning and exactly what you are expecting for that sample data (edit the question to provide both)?  Can you also post the code you are using to fetch and display the data?  It is exceptionally unlikely that the ORDER BY clause is not being honored so the problem is very likely that your data doesn't sort the way you think it should (white space, case sensitivity, etc.) or that you are re-sorting the data in your application before displaying it.

Comment: @Justin - Edited the original question

Comment: @jmg0880 - Thanks.  And just to be clear, does the data in the PE_FQDN column start with the 'hs01' bit of the string in your sample data?

Comment: @justin - Yes that is what it starts with

Comment: Have you tried the SQL in question directly, through a tool like SQL Plus or SQL Developer? Not knowing perl (this is perl right?), is the data coming back from the DB being dumped in a structure that does not maintain order, such as an associative array indexed on the first column? If you test the SQL statement directly, and it works, you might want to add perl tags to bring in experts with that knowledge.

Comment: @Shannon - yes this is perl, and what is happening is the data is being dumped into an array and then displayed in a table.  There is not sorting going on within the perl script.  And no I have not used SQL Plus or SQL Developer, I have never used them before.

Comment: What happens to the output if you change `ORDER BY PE_FQDN` to `ORDER BY PE_FQDN DESC` ?

Comment: @jmg0880 Why is there only two columns in your query but three in the results you are showing?

Comment: @jscheoen - The first column is from user input into a text file that is used by the select statement '?'

Comment: @Catcall - nothing happens, the data stays the same

Comment: @jmg0880: Then the order isn't being determined by that SQL statement. It's being determined by other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your SQL is doing exactly what you're asking it to. You execute your statement eight times. Each time the result set contains only one row, so the the sort does nothing.

You have two options. You can either change your SQL so that you do one select which returns all of the rows that you want sorted how you want it. Or you keep your existing SQL but store the data returned from each execution in an array and sort that array before displaying the results.

Comment: how would I go about creating 1 SELECT statement when the user is inputing multiple lines of data ?

Comment: Instead of having "where site_name = <a value>", you would have "where site_name in <a list of values>".

Answer (score 5):

It isn't the SQL !

The perl code shows two loops.

The outer loop is traversed for each entry in the @raw_data array. The value of each @raw_data 'record' is passed as the SITE_NAME parameter to a SELECT statement.

You are executing multiple SELECT statements, one for each different site. Each individual SELECT returns an ordered row set, but they are all returning a single row for a single site. It is the order of the site names in the @raw_data array that is driving the order of the output.

<---------------------------------------------------------------------->
Old entry which was totally misleading.

I'll offer a few possibilities.

(1) It is a bug. DISTINCT often, but not necessarily, does a sort to remove duplicates. It MAY have, for some reason, determined that the ORDER BY is redundant because of the query plan chosen.

To determine this, check the query plan. EXPLAIN PLAN is simplest, but it is better to use DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR with the sql_id from v$sql for that SQL.

(2) The data is being sorted but there is something causing the sort order to be other than what you expect. Try replacing PE_FQDN with DUMP(PE_FQDN) PE_FQDN. This will show the bytes that it is actually using.

(3) the SELECT doesn't look exactly how you have said. For example

```
SELECT FRED BILL, BILL BILL_TOO
FROM table
ORDER BY BILL
```

will actually order by the column that has the alias BILL (which is the column FRED) and not by the column BILL.

```
SELECT FRED, BULL
FROM table
ORDER BY 'FRED'
```

will sort by the string 'FRED', not the value in the column FRED (and since everything is sorted by the same value, it won't actually do anything).

<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

Comment: you can also use the number of the column - as ORDER BY 3

Comment: this is the result of the DUMP(PE_FQDN):
Typ=1 Len=37: 115,117,114,48,49,46,101,98,97,108,116,105,109,111,114,101,115,116,46,109,100,46,98,97,100,46,99,111,109,99,97,115,116,46,110,101,116

Comment: Maybe I should add that the first column is coming from the user and not from the database.

Comment: @Randy: Using ordinals isn't a recommended practice, because the value is based on the position of the column in the SELECT clause (not the table).  If that changes, so does your sorting.  I don't think it affects the issue experienced, either.